# group_concat returning results in reverse order

Tags: mysql, database, group-concat

I have a table with three columns: type, name, and the weight for ordering. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(type,":",name) ORDER BY weight ASC) FROM table
```

The result is technically sorted correctly, but for some reason, if two rows have the same weight, the order is reversed.

For example, if I have something in this order:

```
(color, blue, 0)
(color, red, 0)
(color, green, 0),
(color, yellow, 1)
```

It'll return

```
color:green,color:red,color:blue,color:yellow
```

This is technically correct, but I want to be able to preserve the order in which it is ordered in the table if they have the same weight. It is also weird because I tried removing the group concat  just to see if the order is still being reversed, and the order is actually being preserved with the following query

```
SELECT concat(type, ":", name) ORDER BY weight ASC FROM table
```

returns

```
color:blue
color:red
color:green
color:yellow
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and if there is a way to preserve the original order in the table if they have the same weight?

Comment: It is happening because when two items are identical in terms of sort order, there is no guarantee as to the order they will be returned. I think the only way to preserve original order is to have another column that reflects original order, e.g. an auto-increment ID or a timestamp (as long as you don't expect more than 1 entry per second), then order by weight first and the order-preserving field second.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, order is not guaranteed when the weight is the same, so I just added an auto-increment ID. Also, I noticed that the order was being reversed because it was ordering the rows with the same weight in alphabetical order, which coincidentally reversed the order of my results.